# Unknown PDF encoding

Tags: pdf, encoding

I have PDF document with Ukrainian text (Cyrillic letters). But when I copy and paste it into some input field, I get something next:

```
ȿɄɈɇɈɆȱɄɈ-ɋɌȺɌɂɋɌɂɑɇɂɃ ȺɇȺɅȱɁ ȼɂȻȱɊɄɈȼɈȽɈ
```

No one text detection or converter didn't help me.

What is it and how to copy normal Ukrainian text?

Comment: Is this in Adobe Acrobat or another tool?

Comment: @Dai I tried to open it with many apps and web browsers. Result is the same. It looks nice but I cannot copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF has likely been created with an embedded font subset and no `toUnicode` mapping. Basically the codes of the characters used in the content of the PDF are mapped to glyphs embedded in the PDF which are displayed, but there is no mapping from these codes to regular Unicode codes so copying them produces gibberish. The only way to extract the original contents would be with some form of OCR.